# How to set property in closure in Groovy, like in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy

Here is the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html), which I don't understand:

```
idea {

  //if you want parts of paths in resulting files (*.iml, etc.) to be replaced by variables (Files)
  pathVariables GRADLE_HOME: file('~/cool-software/gradle')

  module {
    //if for some reason you want to add an extra sourceDirs
    sourceDirs += file('some-extra-source-folder')
```

It sets `idea.module.sourceDirs` value.

How do I implement it in pure Groovy without Gradle? I want to know its underlying merchanism.

Comment: Try searching for "groovy builders".

Answer (score 2):

thanks @Steinar, I use following code fix:

```
def file(String p) {
    new File(p)
}

class Idea {
    class Module {
        Set<File> excludeDirs = []
    }

    void module(Closure c) {
        c.delegate = new Module()
        c()
    }
}

void idea(Closure c) {
    c.delegate = new Idea()
    c()
}

idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs += file("smth")
    }
}
```

Comment: Still you can't do e.g. ```idea.module { ...```, might there be a solution to that too?

Answer (score 0):

With your proposed solution @asullaherc you can't choose between calling `idea { module` and `idea.module { ...` so I would rather go for a different solution.

This is the base class for all of the closures you want to create for your case:

```
class SectionBase extends Closure<Object> {
    SectionClosure() {
        super(null)
    }
    Object doCall(final Closure inner) {
        inner.delegate = this
        inner()
    }
}
```

And this would be an implementation ("Gradle style"):

```
class DependenciesSection extends SectionBase {
    void compile(packageName) {
        println "compile: $packageName"
    }
    void testCompile(packageName) {
        println "testCompile: $packageName"
    }
}
```

Now we make an instance:

```
def dependencies = new DependenciesSection()
```

And mess around with it a little:

```
// You can do it either this way...
dependencies {
    compile 'com.my.package1'
    compile 'com.my.package2'
    testCompile 'com.my.package3'
}

// ...or also the other
dependencies.compile 'com.my.package4'
dependencies.testCompile 'com.my.package5'
```

The output would be:

```
compile: com.my.package1
compile: com.my.package2
testCompile: com.my.package3
compile: com.my.package4
testCompile: com.my.package5
```